# Multiset count in PySpark (using Structured Streaming)

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe with two columns: a and b. Now I would like to have the counts per pair (a, b) and the overall counts for a such that it has the following structure.

Suppose I have the following data:

$(a, b) \in {(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)}$

Then I would like to obtain the following rows:

$[1, 2, {1: 1, 2: 1}]], [2, 1, {3: 1}], [3, 1, {4: 1}]$

In words, the first row expresses the fact that there are 2 observations in total. One observation for b equal to 1 and one observation for b equal to 2. Row 2 contains the information that a=2 got one observation, the observation that b=3. And the third row expresses the fact that there is one observation for a=3, namely b=4.

How can I do this using PySpark?

I tried the following:

```
df = df\
    .groupBy('a', 'b')\
    .agg(
        count('*').alias('count')
    )\
    .groupBy('a')\
    .agg(
        sum('count').alias('total')
    )

df.show()
```

But that obviously does not work. I loose the information about the counts per pair.

Comment: One observation for b equal to 1 and one observation for b equal to 2. Are you considering for two observations of 'b'?